# Google Map V2 android error Inflating class fragment error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, layout-inflater

I am creating an application with tab and I have map in one of the tab, when I open map from it works fine and when I visit some other tab that time also it works fine, but when I come back to the map tab app crashes with this error.

```
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-09 14:10:43.866: E/AndroidRuntime(28184):    at com.research.fragmenttabstudy.tabA.TodaysDealLocation.onCreateView(TodaysDealLocation.java:43)
```

Here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("err","todaysdeal location");
        Log.d("err","todaysdeal location"+inflater.toString()+" "+container.toString()+" ");
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); 
//      map.clear();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todays_deal_location, container,
                false);

        Log.d("err",view.toString());
        back = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Constants.passcode_chk = 0;
                // finish();
                mActivity.popFragments();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.mapp)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/topbar" />

    <!-- <ImageView -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/deallistmenu" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
    <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" -->
    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="9dp" -->
    <!-- android:src="@drawable/deallist_menubtn" /> -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/map_list" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4.8dp" >

        <!-- box layout.................................................................... -->


        <!-- box layout.................................................................... -->

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_location"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

        <!-- <ZoomControls -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/zoomControls" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
        <!-- android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" -->
        <!-- android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" /> -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="50dip"
        android:paddingRight="55dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check line 42 in your xml. or post your xml here..

Answer (score 18):

Your problem is that you have declared the google maps v2 fragment in XML, so every time you inflate the XML it makes a new fragment. However, the id of the fragment is hard-coded in the XML, so it will try to create the new fragment with the same id as the one that is already running. Two running fragments cant have the same id, so the app crashes.

The best way to fix this is to make the map fragment programmatically. A good example of this can be found in ProgrammaticDemoActivity.java part of the google maps example project.

However, if for some reason you must declare your fragment in XML, you can make it work by killing the old map fragment when you leave the view, so the new one can be created.

You can do something like:

```
private void killOldMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSherlockActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

    if(mapFragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
        fM.beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

and then call it from `onDetach()` and `onDestroyView()` to ensure the old map is killed.

As you can see, this is kind of a hack and you are best off just programmatically making your app instead of using XML.

Comment: This causes IllegalStateException as we would be trying to change the state of fragment after onSaveInstance() is called! the hack doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

call this function from onDetach() and onDestroyView() to kill exist fragment transaction.

```
private void commitMaps() {
    if (null != mapFragment) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

sometimes you'll get "IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" if you commit() exist map transaction. To avoid this exception you should use commitAllowingStateLoss() when you remove exist transaction.

Difference between  [commit() and commitAllowingStateLoss()](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity extends fragment activity and replace

```
map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and remove "`android:layout_below="@+id/tv_location" because it is inside relative layout`"

Go with this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One map fragment is already created, and when you are trying to get back to the map page, its trying to create another fragment on the top of it. Below code is finally working fine for me:

XML:

```html
<fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Please note that I have used SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment.

JAVA:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The first problem I see here with the code you presented is this line:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapp)).getMap();
```

You trying to get a `SupportMapFragment` object using the usual `FragmentManager`. this is wrong.
To get the `SupportMapFragment` object you have to use `SupportFragmentManager` like this:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapp)).getMap();
```

But my guess is that the problems you experiance right now are not yet derived from this mistake.
I think you referencing the `google-play-services` library of the `google-support-v4` library the wrong way.

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to add `Google Map API V2` to you application:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

if you min SDK is 11 then you can change the fragment to this code:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_location"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: But, Emil here I am extending fragment so I cant use getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: then get an instance of MapFragment instead of SupportMapFragment.

Comment: for what min sdk you are writing you application?

Comment: check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/12/add-reference-library-google-play.html)